# Make "NOT NULL" default in Postgresql 9.2

Tags: postgresql, database-design, postgresql-9.2

I use `NOT NULL` a lot when creating columns.

Is there a way to make this default when defining columns?  In other words, make column `is_nullable` default to `NO`. (I realize this would make it harder for me to set it to `YES` later one.)

Comment: Are you asking how to save yourself from having to type 4 additional characters for each column definition?

Comment: Changing the default behaviour of the `CREATE TABLE` and `ALTER TABLE` statements requires recompiling I think. Postgres is open source, so I guess you could do that. But the details would be a C question.

Comment: You could do that, but then you're making a PostgreSql server that is parsing non-ANSI-compatible SQL in a fairly profound way.  Your DDL would not be translatable across various systems, and backups/ restores could end up a complete mess.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs Thanks. That clears things up.

Comment: @ypercube Thanks. That answers the question.

Answer (score 2):

YOU have to define NOT NULL when creating a table as described in [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-createtable.html) :

NOT NULL ==>
The column is not allowed to contain null values.

Examples :

```
CREATE TABLE films (
    code        char(5) CONSTRAINT firstkey PRIMARY KEY,
    title       varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    did         integer NOT NULL,
    date_prod   date,
    kind        varchar(10),
    len         interval hour to minute
);
```

Define two NOT NULL column constraints on the table distributors, one of which is explicitly given a name:

```
CREATE TABLE distributors (
    did     integer CONSTRAINT no_null NOT NULL,
    name    varchar(40) NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure what he's asking is the exact opposite of that.